# sudo python setup.py install show error 403

Tags: python, ubuntu

```
theasad@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/stratum-mining/externals/stratum$ python setup.py install
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.28.tar.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 3, in <module>
    use_setuptools()
  File "/home/theasad/stratum-mining/externals/stratum/distribute_setup.py", line 145, in use_setuptools
    return _do_download(version, download_base, to_dir, download_delay)
  File "/home/theasad/stratum-mining/externals/stratum/distribute_setup.py", line 124, in _do_download
    to_dir, download_delay)
  File "/home/theasad/stratum-mining/externals/stratum/distribute_setup.py", line 194, in download_setuptools
    src = urlopen(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: SSL is required
```

Comment: Try executing `sudo apt install openssl`

Comment: @MegaIng, ...could you explain a bit more why that's expected to work? Normally, I'd expect this to be the PIP server (accessed over HTTP) indicating that the current release of the server only supports HTTPS, and that SSL needs to be used in the link being used to specify the library to install.

Comment: Remove the distribute_setup.py and edit setup.py to remove these lines.

From
-from distribute_setup import use_setuptools
-use_setuptools()
-py_modules=['distribute_setup',],

Then run this to make sure that distribute is up-to-date.
pip install --upgrade distribute

Then try installing again with.
sudo python setup.py install